# How to access data_control_h handle from another app on tizen?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I want to access a data control service from two different UI consumer apps. I am creating the `data_control_h` handle with data control provider id in one app. ex: `data_control_sql_create(&(ad->provider_h));`. I am making operation on it. Now I want to access this provider `provider_h` handle from the other UI app. How can I do this?

And if I add a service app as a consumer app along with those two UI apps, how can I access the data control provider on that service app without closing the UI app?

If I create two different data control handle with same provider id at the same time, will it work? Is there an easy or good way?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to some guides before developing an application.
https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/app-management/data-control

1. You can't access the handle from the other UI app. In order to communicate with other UI apps, it is necessary to create a new handle to use an apis of data control.
2. If the service app is alive, it is possible.
3. You can make two different data control handle with same provider id.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have referred to the document multiple times. Something I miss out while reading and some things are not mentioned.